# How to make all Hyperlinks in Django REST Framework relative?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there any easy way to use relative to Root urls instead of absolute ones? By default DRF returns something like this:

```json
{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:34503/items/4/",
    ...
    "parent": "http://127.0.0.1:34503/items/1/",
    "stargazers": "http://127.0.0.1:34503/items/4/stargazers",
}
```

I would like it to be:

```json
{
    "url": "/items/4/",
    ...
    "parent": "/items/1/",
    "stargazers": "/items/4/stargazers",
}
```

Any ideas?

I am using `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    stargazers = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='item-stargazers')

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['url', 'id', ..., 'stargazers']

class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

Comment: Can you share how you are serializing at the moment, likely this can result in better answers (with a minimum of changes).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, updated with some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation on [*Absolute and relative URLs*](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#absolute-and-relative-urls) states:

> If you do want to use **relative URLs**, you should **explicitly pass `{'request': None}`** in the serializer context.

You thus should serialize this with:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # …
    
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['url', id', 'stargazers']
```

and then serialize this with:

```
ItemSerializer(queryset, context={'request', None})
```

For a `ViewSet`, you can overide the `get_serializer_context` method:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    # …

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        result = super().get_serializer_context()
        result['request'] = None
        return result
```